# How to join these two tables to one in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I have two SQLite tables which I would like to join. These tables look like:

Table1:

```
address  size
2000     size56
2001     size56
2002     size09
```

Table2:

```
address  size
3000     size56
3001     size56
3002     size56
3003     size09
```

I want to join these two tables to one by column.size in SQL. I hope to get the following result:

Output:

```
address  size    address  size
2000     size56  3000     size56
2001     size56  3001     size56
2002     size09  3003     size09
```

Comment: You want to drop 3002?

Comment: if @GordonLinoff is right i don't know. Otherwise what about `SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.size = table2.size`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straight join of the tables will not solve your problem because you want to join each row of Table1 to only 1 row of Table2.
Use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
select
  t1.address address1, t1.size size1,
  t2.address address2, t2.size size2
from (
  select *, row_number() over(partition by size order by address) rn
  from Table1
) t1 inner join  (
  select *, row_number() over(partition by size order by address) rn
  from Table2
) t2 on t2.size = t1.size and t2.rn = t1.rn 
order by address1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ku79xgbu6jML2nJoCPwSUZ/0).
Results:

```
| address1 | size1  | address2 | size2  |
| -------- | ------ | -------- | ------ |
| 2000     | size56 | 3000     | size56 |
| 2001     | size56 | 3001     | size56 |
| 2002     | size09 | 3003     | size09 |
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! your answer is my need